# Tensor product of submodules is a submodule of the tensor product?

Tags: modules, tensor-products

If $M',N'$ be submodules of $M$ and $N$ respectively. Then is it true that $M'\otimes N'$ is a submodule of $M\otimes N$?

I think it should not be true.
I considered $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z_2}$ as submodules of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z_2}$ then $2\otimes 1=0 \in \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z_2}$ and $2\otimes 1 \neq 0 \in \mathbb{2Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z_2}$.

I think elements of $M' \otimes N'$ are very different from the elements $M\otimes N$, just like elements of $\mathbb{Z_3}$ is very different from elements of $Z_4$ although both contains $\bar{1},\bar{2}$.

Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true and your counterexample is correct. The problem is that tensoring by $M$ or $N$ can fail to respect injections if $M$ or $N$ aren't [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module), and in your example $N$ is not flat.

It is true if $M$ and $N'$ are both flat (in which case we have injections $M' \otimes N' \hookrightarrow M \otimes N' \hookrightarrow M \otimes N$) or if $M'$ and $N$ are both flat (in which case we have injections $M' \otimes N' \hookrightarrow M' \otimes N \hookrightarrow M \otimes N$). Notably this means it's true if $M$ and $N$ are torsion-free modules over a Dedekind domain (which implies that $M, N, M', N'$ are all flat), which is a useful special case.